# Javascript not getting textfield value

Tags: javascript

Why in JavaScript `var frstNo = document.getElementById("frsNo").value;` in global space is not giving me value in text field?

I'm getting value only when I write `var rstNo = document.getElementById("frsNo");` in global space and `frstNo.value` in local space?

Comment: Well, value is for input fields? What do you want? Take what is inner paragraph e.g?

Comment: What Quentin said, but you should post a [mre]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Because they get the value at **different times**.

If it is outside of any function, then you get the value as the document loads (i.e. **before** the user has a chance to type anything).

If it is in a function called by an event handler, then it will get the value when that event fires. Typically the event handler will be something like `submit` and the user won't do anything to trigger that until **after** they have typed something into the field.